# JQuery Validation: Dynamic form not validating

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form which is being generated based on a category selection by user. For every category there are some dynamic fields which I append into HTML using jQuery get call.

Problem:

Validation works perfect for the first loaded form but when I change the category and a new form is loaded then the validation does not get applied on the dynamically generated fields whereas it gets applied on the fields which are static on the page.

Here is the page: http://goo.gl/RXrHE

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You may need to re-initalize the form using jquery validate, but I am not sure what part you're looking that is causing the issue since I don't seem to know how to get to that form.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for solution to same problem. Here is the fix:

I added rules for the dynamic fields via the rules('add', ...) function, after they have been added to the form.